# List DPI of all images in folder

Tags: terminal, linux-mint, dpi

I'm running Linux Mint 17. I need a way to list the DPIs of every .png image inside a folder.

I've tried the commands:

```
file *.png
identify *png
exiv2 *.png
```

but none print out explicitly the DPI value.

How can I access this information via the terminal?

Answer (score 3):

[DPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) is not a property of a bitmap image, it is a measure of *output* (in other words, **physical** media) dot density: "DPI refers to the physical dot density of an image when it is reproduced as a real physical entity, for example printed onto paper." So that is literally impossible.

On the other hand, an image may contain information relating to how it *should* be reproduced. For example, if you print a complex image where every pixel counts at 1200 DPI it may be too small to understand. On the other hand, a simple logo may be recognizable up to very large DPI. And conversely, rendering at a very small DPI may reduce the graphical appeal of some images more than others, depending on whether the image consists mainly of vertical/-horizontal lines (looks similar at different DPI) or of smooth curves (get aliased at small DPI). An application may let you specify the target DPI when saving a *vector* image as a bitmap, to be able to reproduce it elsewhere in a way which looks the same as it did on your screen.

Comment: Ok, I'm really lost here. I am being requested to check that the "resolution of my images is at least 300 DPI". What does this mean in the context of your answer? Also, matplotlib allows you to manually set the DPI value of an image when stored in a file. Why can I not check the DPI used when creating that image by checking the properties of the final file?

Answer (score 1):

This is the command I was after:

```
identify -units PixelsPerInch -verbose *.png | grep Resolution
```

Adding it as the answer but l0b0's answer has some really nice info nonetheless.